# seleniumでwebdriverをimportできません

Tags: anaconda, selenium-webdriver, import

seleniumをinstallした上で `from selenium import webdriver` を実行すると、以下のエラーが表示されてしまいます。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 36, in <module>
    from .service import Service
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/service.py", line 21, in <module>
    class Service(service.Service):
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.common.service' has no attribute 'Service'
```

どなたか解決策をご教授できませんでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「seleniumをimportした上で」は「seleniumをinstallした上で」のtypoでは？ それからあまり関係は無いかもしれませんが、PCの機種・CPU・OS種類/版数・あとはどんな方法(AnacondaNavigatorのGUI/Anacondaコマンドプロンプトのcondaコマンドまたはpipコマンド/Jupyter上の!pipコマンド等)でinstallしたかといった情報があると何かの助けになるかもしれません。ただし最初のimportでエラーになっているのでは、ちょっと望みが薄そうですが。思い切ってPython環境を新規に追加作成して、そこで試してみた方が良いかもしれません。

Comment: ご丁寧に回答有難うございます。冒頭はtypoですね。。seleniumはmacのターミナル上から、conda install seleniumでinstallしました。またpython環境の新規追加とはAnacandaをuninstallして、再度installという認識であっていますか？何卒ご回答のほど宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: Anacondaを使っているならUninstall/再Installするのではなくて、こちらの記事 [MacでPython、Anaconda、VSCodeのインストールとPython開発環境を構築する方法](https://www.nblog09.com/w/2020/11/21/anaconda-vscode/) の`03 | Anacondaで仮想環境を作成する`ように新規の独立したPython仮想環境を作成・アクティベートして、他の何かの影響を受けにくい形で試すことです。

Comment: なるほど！記事送って下さりありがとうございます。仮想環境作成、アクティベートして再度seleniumのimport試してみます。

Comment: ダメでしたか、それでしたらAnacondaのアンインストール/再インストール [MacのAnacondaのアンインストール方法](https://yu88life.com/5/) から行う方法を試して、それでもダメならMacOSを初期状態に戻してからやってみるとか、段階的に試してみる感じでしょうか。他には同じMacOSのAnaconda/Python/Selenium等も同じ版数で同様のことを行っている記事を探して同じ手順で試してみるくらいでしょうか。

Comment: 今、仮想環境上でconda install seleniumではなく conda install -c conda-forge seleniumでinstallしてみたらimportできました！私のinstallの仕方が間違っていたようです。。丁寧に色々と教えて下さり有難うございました！

Comment: なるほど、ではそういう事例があったということで原因と対策を自己回答してみてください。

Comment: かしこまりました！

Answer (score 0):

原因：pythonのモジュールinstallのやり方
対策：「conda install ~」でモジュールをインストールできなければ、「conda install -c conda-forge」で試してみる。その際には、新たにpython仮想環境を作成、アクティベートし、他の何らかの影響を受けない形で行う。